# How to pass a list as an environment variable to an AWS Lambda function from a JSON config file?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a JSON file that is going to contain a number of different lists per client that I am deploying for. These lists are going to serve as container overrides for an ECS task that my Lambda function will be invoking. The JSON config file would look something like this:

```
{
    "clientName": {
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "value": "value1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And my serverless.yml would look something like this:

```
environment:
    CONTAINER_ENVIRONMENT: ${file(serverlessConfig.json):${env:CLIENT_NAME}.environment}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Could not resolve "CONTAINER_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable: Unsupported environment variable format:

[
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "value": "value1"
    }
]
```

I've tried using CloudFormation intrinsic functions such as Fn::Join and Fn::ToJsonString. These both threw an error when trying to run locally using `sls invoke local` (the errors were the same as the above). After some digging it seems that these functions aren't compatible with the serverless environment property.

The only thing that has worked so far is storing the list as a string in a .env file, but that's not really ideal since these configs could take a number of different environment objects.

Is there any way to get this to work with the setup that I have going?

Comment: Probably not relevant, but be aware that Lambda environment variables for a given function can't exceed 4KB in aggregate.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply ship the various JSON blobs in files (either uploaded with your Lambda function package or in S3 or DynamoDB or Parameter Store) and then your environment variable indicates which JSON to read (rather than contain the actual encoded JSON content).

Comment: @jarmod. I like that idea. I considered doing that earlier but I'm too stubborn and wanted to see if I could get it working this way. It doesn't look possible at this time so I will likely end up using Dynamo as you suggested.

Comment: I suspect that you could make your solution work with some minimal pre-processing of the JSON files beforehand in your build/deploy process. Perhaps base64-encode abc.json to abc.b64 and have the CF template populate the environment variable from that b64 file. Your Lambda global init can load the env var and base4-decode it to JSON and then JSON load/parse that.